# How can I terminate mobile app order transaction?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, backend, mobile-development

I have a React Native app and such a confusing case.

Let's say, my app is an online food delivery app. I would like to create an order. When I create an order, I call API request to the server. While waiting to create the order, my app shows a loader. And suddenly, my app goes offline (bad internet connection). And I use apisauce library, which I put timeout for API request. Because of my app is offline, I can't receive the response and eventually the request timeout. The app shows up unable to create order prompt. But in the server, the order is created.

Is there any way out, to solve this ? If the app suddenly offline, can I terminate the request ? Or can I receive any response whenever my app is getting back online ?

Please give me any suggestions, whether I should modify my app or the backend server to handle this issue.

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure this is a perfect answer or not but when the order is created at your backend you can send some data as order id and other necessary information which is part of your order and ask for the acknowledgment from the app. So when the order is created at the backend and if the app if offline and you send the data back to the app it won't be able to get the data and eventually will not send the acknowledgment for receiving the data, the backend will not get the acknowledgment and you can reverse the order.

Comment: I see @PramodYadav. So it is like the client (mobile app) send 2 requests. First one is the order data, and the second one is confirming to the server that client had received Order Id. I will consider this solution. Thank you so much.

Still open for other kind of solutions !

Comment: This one is the easiest and simplest one which came to my mind.